# Symfony2 - How to put label and input for checkboxes/radios in a same line?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

In my form I have some checkboxes,
but by default, **I have** :

- the first radio widget
- the first label
- the second radio widget
- the label

Here is the html code generated by SYmfony2 :

```
  <div>
    <input ...>
    <label ...></label>
    <input ...>
    <label ...></label>
  </div>
```

What **I want** is to have :

the first radio widget the first label
the second radio widget the second label

The html code would be :

```
  <label .....><input ....></label>
```

I think I have to override the choice_widget but don't know how to put input and label on the same line

Here is the choice_widget I may need to override :

```
    {% block choice_widget %}
        {% spaceless %}
            {% if expanded %}
                <div {{ block('widget_container_attributes') }}>
                   {% for child in form %}
                      {{ form_widget(child) }}  {{ form_label(child) }}
                   {% endfor %}
                </div>
            {% else %}
                <select {{ block('widget_attributes') }}{% if multiple %} multiple="multiple"{% endif %}>
                {% if empty_value is not none %}
                     <option value="">{{ empty_value|trans }}</option>
                {% endif %}
                {% if preferred_choices|length > 0 %}
                    {% set options = preferred_choices %}
                    {{ block('widget_choice_options') }}
                        {% if choices|length > 0 and separator is not none %}
                            <option disabled="disabled">{{ separator }}</option>
                       {% endif %}
                {% endif %}
                {% set options = choices %}
                {{ block('widget_choice_options') }}
                </select>
           {% endif %}
      {% endspaceless %}
   {% endblock choice_widget %}
```

Comment: Can't you just use CSS to style them?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but can you tell me how to ? I am a beginner in computer science.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I had the same problem, and I was unable to find a solution so I worked it out on my own. You are correct that you do need to override the `{% block choice_widget %}` block. The first step is to remove the `{{ form_label(child) }}` line from the `{% if expanded %}` section that prints out a separate label.

```
{% block choice_widget %}
{% spaceless %}
    {% if expanded %}
        <div {{ block('widget_container_attributes') }}>
        {% for child in form %}
            {{ form_widget(child) }}
        {#  {{ form_label(child) }} <--------------------- remove this line #}  
        {% endfor %}
        </div>
    {% else %}
    <select {{ block('widget_attributes') }}{% if multiple %} multiple="multiple"{% endif %}>
        {% if empty_value is not none %}
            <option value="">{{ empty_value|trans }}</option>
        {% endif %}
        {% if preferred_choices|length > 0 %}
            {% set options = preferred_choices %}
            {{ block('widget_choice_options') }}
            {% if choices|length > 0 and separator is not none %}
                <option disabled="disabled">{{ separator }}</option>
            {% endif %}
        {% endif %}
        {% set options = choices %}
        {{ block('widget_choice_options') }}
    </select>
    {% endif %}
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock choice_widget %}
```

Now you will just need to handle printing the label in the `{% block checkbox_widget %}` block.

```
{% block checkbox_widget %}
{% spaceless %}
    <label  for="{{ id }}"><input type="checkbox" {{ block('widget_attributes') }}{% if value is defined %} value="{{ value }}"{% endif %}{% if checked %} checked="checked"{% endif %} />{{ label|trans }}</label>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock checkbox_widget %}
```

You will need to do the same for `{% block radio_widget %}` since it would not otherwise have a label now.

```
{% block radio_widget %}
{% spaceless %}
    <label  for="{{ id }}"><input type="radio" {{ block('widget_attributes') }}{% if value is defined %} value="{{ value }}"{% endif %}{% if checked %} checked="checked"{% endif %} />{{ label|trans }}</label>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock radio_widget %}
```

Comment: Don't know why this was down-voted as it produces the output that was requested on 2.0.x

Comment: Does not work for Symfony 2.3 since choice_widget has been split into choice_widget_expanded and choice_widget_collapsed. If you follow this advice verbatim if will affect select's behaviour. Se bellow for updated solution.

Comment: How is it possible to apply `label_attr` with this solution? E.g. if I want to add a class through `form_widget` to the label.

Comment: Hi @mwld. I haven't been actively working with Symfony for quite a while, so I am not sure how to answer your question. I would advise posting it as a new question as this comment is unlikely to get many views. Good luck.

Answer (score 13):

With help from Alberto Gaona and James, Symfony 2.4 correct solution to integrate BS3 radio AND checkboxes is as follow :

In your view you have :

```
{% form_theme form 'AcmeDemoBundle:Form:fields.html.twig' %}

// A radio or checkbox input
{{ form_widget(form.example) }}
```

Then in your fields.html.twig (which overrides https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/form_div_layout.html.twig ; see http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html)

```
{# src/Acme/DemoBundle/Resources/views/Form/fields.html.twig #}

{% block choice_widget_expanded %}
{% spaceless %}
    <div {{ block('widget_container_attributes') }}>
    {% for child in form %}
        {% if multiple %}
            <div class="checkbox">
        {% else %}
            <div class="radio">
        {% endif %}

        {{ form_widget(child) }}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock choice_widget_expanded %}

{% block checkbox_widget %}
{% spaceless %}
{% if label is empty %}
    {% set label = name|humanize %}
{% endif %}
    <label  for="{{ id }}">
        <input type="checkbox" {{ block('widget_attributes') }}{% if value is defined %} value="{{ value }}"{% endif %}{% if checked %} checked="checked"{% endif %} />{{ label|trans({}, translation_domain) }}
    </label>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock checkbox_widget %}

{% block radio_widget %}
{% spaceless %}
{% if label is empty %}
    {% set label = name|humanize %}
{% endif %}
    <label  for="{{ id }}">
        <input type="radio" {{ block('widget_attributes') }}{% if value is defined %} value="{{ value }}"{% endif %}{% if checked %} checked="checked"{% endif %} />{{ label|trans({}, translation_domain) }}
    </label>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock radio_widget %}
```

Comment: If you want to enable HTML in your labels, change `label|trans` to `label|trans|raw`

Answer (score 11):

NOTE: Updated Bob F solution for Symfony 2.3 (see https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.3/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/form_div_layout.html.twig):

Override choice_widget_expanded:

```
{% block choice_widget_expanded %}
{% spaceless %}
    <div {{ block('widget_container_attributes') }}>
    {% for child in form %}
        {{ form_widget(child) }}
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock choice_widget_expanded %}
```

Override checkbox (bootstrap style):

```
{% block checkbox_widget %}
{% spaceless %}
    <label  for="{{ id }}" class="checkbox {% if checked %}checked{% endif %}" ><span class="icons"><span class="first-icon fui-checkbox-unchecked"></span><span class="second-icon fui-checkbox-checked"></span></span><input type="checkbox" {{ block('widget_attributes') }}{% if value is defined %} value="{{ value }}"{% endif %}{% if checked %} checked="checked"{% endif %} />{{ label|trans }}</label>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock checkbox_widget %}
```

Override radiobutton

```
{% block radio_widget %}
{% spaceless %}
    <label  for="{{ id }}"><input type="radio" {{ block('widget_attributes') }}{% if value is defined %} value="{{ value }}"{% endif %}{% if checked %} checked="checked"{% endif %} />{{ label|trans }}</label>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock radio_widget %}
```

Comment: Put these blocks in a separate file and before using form_widget on a field you may do {% form_theme form.field '::theme.html.twig' %} to use this. Took me a while to figure out how to actually use these for just one field :)

Answer (score 2):

When a label is rendered it will include a `for` attribute - this links the `label` to the `input` - [see the docs on `label` here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/label) changing the output to what you suggested is just another way of linking the `label` and the `input`

If you want the label to display to the left of the input you need to change your template to :

```
{% for child in form %}
   <div>
      {{ form_label(child) }}  {{ form_widget(child) }} 
   </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Which renders the `label` before the `input` and then this creates the following output

```
<div>
  <div>
    <label ...></label>
    <input ...>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label ...></label>
    <input ...>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can then apply some CSS styling to make it display inline :

```
​div label {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
}​
```

By default - without any CSS the `label` would line up before the `input` with this HTML layout - but the `inline-block` allows you to also use the `width` attribute to ensure all fields are lined up correctly - irrespective of the length of label text

[Working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/MjhAR/1/)

Comment: OK thanks it works with your css but I would like to use something like that instead {{ form_widget(form.field1, {'attr' : {'class': 'some_css'} }) }} with .some_css {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
}​ and it doesn't work that way

Comment: @reveclaire form_widget is the input. You need form_label

Answer (score 1):

<del>Putting the form input inside the label tag would result in broken HTML.</del>

What is your goal? If you are simply looking to make the label and input show on the same line in the browser, then you could use css:

```
input, label {
 display: inline;
}
```

Comment: That HTML is perfectly valid - putting the `input` inside a `label` is fine - it just associates the `label` with the `input` - just like the `for` attribute does - [see the HTML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.9)

Comment: @MrGlass - I was about to suggest the same solution as its what I've just done - just to find out you beat me to it by nearly 5 years! lol

Answer (score 1):

In Symfony 3+, you can simply pass the radio-inline class to your form via label_attr:

```
$builder->add('type', ChoiceType::class, [
    'expanded' => true, 
    'label_attr' => ['class' => 'radio-inline']
]);
```

No need to create custom widgets or so...

you can guess those things by looking at the bootstrap_4_layout.html.twig offered by Symfony in your vendor directory (src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/bootstrap_4_layout.html.twig)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In Symfony 2.4, this doesn't work quite as expected.

```
{% block checkbox_widget %}
{% spaceless %}
  <label  for="{{ id }}"><input type="checkbox" {{ block('widget_attributes') }}{% if value is defined %} value="{{ value }}"{% endif %}{% if checked %} checked="checked"{% endif %} />{{ label|trans }}</label>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock checkbox_widget %}
```

...the label is not available. You need to add the following:

```
{% if label is empty %}
  {% set label = name|humanize %}
{% endif %}
```

So a complete solution is:

```
{% block checkbox_widget %}
{% if label is empty %}
  {% set label = name|humanize %}
{% endif %}
{% spaceless %}
  <label  for="{{ id }}"><input type="checkbox" {{ block('widget_attributes') }}{% if value is defined %} value="{{ value }}"{% endif %}{% if checked %} checked="checked"{% endif %} />{{ label|trans }}</label>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock checkbox_widget %}
```

Answer (score 0):

A label is pretty trivial, so I personally preferred to render it manually.

Quick and dirty in your twig:

```
<label for="field">
    {{ form_widget(form.field) }} Field Label
</label>
```

I would have liked if Symfony had a simpler solution for this but whatever.

Of course the above answers are perhaps more elegant and what not. ;)

Answer (score -1):

You can overide the form_row function like that (modified to fit the temple label / checkbox of twitter bootstrap ) :
(in that exemple it's "checkbox" but i think with "radio" it works the same)

```
{% extends 'form_div_layout.html.twig' %}

{% block field_row %}
{% spaceless %}
    {% if 'checkbox' in types %}
        {% if not compound %}
            {% set label_attr = label_attr|merge({'for': id}) %}
        {% endif %}
        {% if required %}
            {% set label_attr = label_attr|merge({'class': (label_attr.class|default('') ~ ' required')|trim}) %}
        {% endif %}
        {% if label is empty %}
            {% set label = name|humanize %}
        {% endif %}
        <label class="checkbox" {% for attrname, attrvalue in label_attr %} {{ attrname }}="{{ attrvalue }}"{% endfor %}>{{ label|trans({}, translation_domain) }}
           {{ block('checkbox_widget') }}
        </label>
    {% else %}
        {{ parent() }}
    {% endif %}
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock field_row %}
```