# How to show label for overrided checkbox in Symfony Twig

Tags: symfony, checkbox, label, overriding, twig

I've overrided the Twig template for my forms in my symfony application so that I could have more control over the labels for checkboxes.

However, I am having problems with the checkbox label.

Here is the code I overrided in my custom template file:

```
{# Labels #}
{% block form_label %}
    {% spaceless %}
        {% if label is not sameas(false) %}
            {% if not compound %}
                {% set label_attr = label_attr|merge({'for': id}) %}
            {% endif %}
            {% if required %}
                {% set label_attr = label_attr|merge({'class': (label_attr.class|default('') ~ ' required')|trim}) %}
            {% endif %}
            {% if label is empty %}
                {% set label = name|humanize %}
            {% endif %}
        {% endif %}
        {% if 'checkbox' not in block_prefixes %}
             <label{% for attrname, attrvalue in label_attr %} {{ attrname }}="{{ attrvalue }}"{% endfor %}>{{ label|trans({}, translation_domain) }}</label>
        {% endif %}
    {% endspaceless %}
{% endblock form_label %}

{# Checkboxes #}
{% block button_label %}{% endblock %}
{% block checkbox_widget %}
{% spaceless %}
    <label for="{{ id }}">
        <input type="checkbox" {{ block('widget_attributes') }}{% if value is defined %} value="{{ value }}"{% endif %}{% if checked %} checked="checked"{% endif %} />
    {{ label }}</label>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock checkbox_widget %}
```

It works fine but I can't get the label text node for checkboxes working.

When I have a checkbox it generates something like:

```
<label><input type="checkbox"/></label>
```

Where it should be:

```
<label><input type="checkbox"/>Label Here</label>
```

Any clue on how to make the label string apear after the checkbox?

**Edit:**

I came to a solution, that worked pretty fine, but I am not sure if it the best.

```
{% block form_row %}
{% spaceless %}
    <div>
        {{ form_errors(form) }}
        {% if 'checkbox'  in block_prefixes %}
            {{ form_widget(form) }}
            {{ form_label(form) }}
        {% elseif 'radio'  in block_prefixes %}
            {{ form_widget(form) }}
            {{ form_label(form) }}
        {% else %}
            {{ form_label(form) }}
            {{ form_widget(form) }}
        {% endif %}

    </div>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock form_row %}
```

Comment: Code you implement with block_prefixes is what I was looking for. I need to give some style just when label is for a checkbox field. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can remove the label in `{% block choice_widget %}` to prevent it from appearing in the default spot.

```
{% block choice_widget %}
{% spaceless %}
    {% if expanded %}
        <div {{ block('widget_container_attributes') }}>
        {% for child in form %}
            {{ form_widget(child) }}
            {{ form_label(child) }}             {# HERE #}  
        {% endfor %}
        </div>
    {% else %}
//....
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock choice_widget %}
```

If you do so, you would have to override the `{% block radio_widget %}` too. Otherwise it won't have a label.

```
<label  for="{{ id }}"><input type="radio" {{ block('widget_attributes') }}{% if value is defined %} value="{{ value }}"{% endif %}{% if checked %} checked="checked"{% endif %} />{{ label|trans }}</label>
```

You can then remove the `{% if 'checkbox' not in block_prefixes %}` line you put in `{% block form_label %}`.

It worked for me.

[Symfony2 - How to put label and input for checkboxes/radios in a same line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11507217/symfony2-how-to-put-label-and-input-for-checkboxes-radios-in-a-same-line)

Edit :

it seems that they split the `{% block choice_widget %}` in 2.3.3. You have to edit the choice_expanded block now, and remove the label line as above.

```
{% block choice_widget_expanded %}
{% spaceless %}
    <div {{ block('widget_container_attributes') }}>
    {% for child in form %}
        {{ form_widget(child) }}
        {{ form_label(child) }}           {# There #}
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock choice_widget_expanded %}
```

Comment: I think Symfony 2.3.3 has gone through considerable changes because I just can't find the twig structure you presented above in the default twig layout file so that I could work on it.

Comment: I edited my answer for the new `form_div_layout.html.twig` structure in  symfony 2.3.3