# Symfony2 forms how to set class for choice input fields?

Tags: php, forms, class, symfony

as above how to set class for input fields ?

what i got so far: the form builder class:

```
    $builder->add('rate', 'choice', array(
                'choices' => array(
                    1 => 1,
                    2 => 2,
                    3 => 3,
                    4 => 4,
                    5 => 5,
                ),
                'multiple' => false,
                'expanded' => true,
                'attr' => array('disabled' => 'disabled', 'class' => 'star'),
            ))
            ->add('save', 'submit');
```

so here the line:

```
'attr' => array('disabled' => 'disabled', 'class' => 'star'),
```

sets the class for dive not for each input ratio button

here the generated html:

```
<form action="/app_dev.php/pl/applications/vote/Google%20Earth%20DirectX" method="post">

    <div id="vote_rate"     disabled="disabled" class="star"><label class="radio"><input type="radio" id="vote_rate_0" name="vote[rate]" required="required"    class="" value="1" />
            1
        </label><label class="radio"><input type="radio" id="vote_rate_1" name="vote[rate]" required="required"    class="" value="2" />
            2
        </label><label class="radio"><input type="radio" id="vote_rate_2" name="vote[rate]" required="required"    class="" value="3" checked="checked" />
            3
        </label><label class="radio"><input type="radio" id="vote_rate_3" name="vote[rate]" required="required"    class="" value="4" />
            4
        </label><label class="radio"><input type="radio" id="vote_rate_4" name="vote[rate]" required="required"    class="" value="5" />
            5
        </label></div>
  <div><button type="submit" id="vote_save" name="vote[save]">Save</button></div><input type="hidden" id="vote__token" name="vote[_token]"    class=" not-removable form-control" value="35bc6584f16d20796946cac15f9e18e62dec3cab" />
</form>
```

as we can see my builder is setting up the class for div `vote_rate` and my input fields have `class=""` and i want it to be `class="star"` and my question is how to set it up in builder or other way ?

Comment: One way to go but not advisable ,loop through all radios with jquery and add a class

Comment: there is no way with symfony2 ?

Comment: this will give you an idea http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11507217/symfony2-how-to-put-label-and-input-for-checkboxes-radios-in-a-same-line

Comment: thanks a lot. it did helped me! i ovveride radio_widget and it works great!

Comment: it will helpful for future visitors if post the solution of your problem as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in case to set the input field class i ovveride the radio widget

in my form template i added:

```
{% form_theme form 'ApplicationsBundle:Form:fields.html.twig' %}
```

and here is my fields.html.twig:

```
{% block radio_widget %}
{% spaceless %}
<input type="radio" class="star" {{ block('widget_attributes') }}{% if value is defined %} value="{{ value }}"{% endif %}{% if checked %} checked="checked"{% endif %} disabled="disabled"/>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock radio_widget %}
```

also to make it work you need to call your form as:

```
{{ form_widget(form) }}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `choice_attr` option will allow you to add attributes (including classes) to each choice (radio in your example).

```
        'choice_attr' => function($val, $key, $index) {
            return ['disabled' => 'disabled', 'class' => 'star'];
        },
```

You can use `$val`, `$key` and `$index` to determine what to return.