# Access to template data in Twig

Tags: php, symfony, twig, templating

I am creating a custom form field in Symfony2 and here is my template :

```
{% block rating_widget %}
{% spaceless %}
    <div {{ block('widget_container_attributes') }}>
        {% for child in form %}
            <label for="{{ id }}">
                <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
            </label>
            <input type="radio" {{ block('widget_attributes') }}{% if value is defined %} value="{{ value }}"{% endif %} />
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock %}
```

I want to access to the data inside of `{{ block('widget_attributes') }}`.

For example, i found these: `{{ id }}` and `{{ value }}` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11507217/symfony2-how-to-put-label-and-input-for-checkboxes-radios-in-a-same-line), and it works pretty well, but i can't find any documentation or example to get the others.

Anybody have an idea or a link?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it's pretty easy in fact. After some tests, I figured out...

For the field "`id=`", the twig field is `{{ id }}`, so I tried for `name=""` as `{{ name }}` and it worked. And it overrides the `{{ block('widget_attributes') }}`, so the meta data is not duplicated.

In fact for any `<meta-data>=""`, just use `{{ <meta-data> }}`.